# Why do we sometimes need to import module1.module2 but sometimes not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

Why do we need to `import module1.module2` if we can just `import module1`?
**Example:**
Why do we need `import tkinter.messagebox` and do `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno(“blah text”)` when we also can do `import os` and still can do `os.path.join(“/“, “blah”)`?

I use `import os` in my code regularly, and I saw in someone else’s code the `import tkinter.messagebox`.

Comment: because with `import os.path`, you import only "path", with `import os` you import everything in `os`. Same difference as `from foo import bar` vs `from foo import *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one rationale. Generally when people do a

```
import os
```

more often than not, they use methods that belong to both `os.path` and `os` like `os.path. abspath()` and `os.getcwd()`. So importing `os` makes more sense. If you are assured you are going to use just the methods in `os.path` you might as well `import os.path` and it is perfectly fine.

Similarly, if you are sure you are gonna be using just the methods in `tkinter.messagebox` you do

```
import tkinter.messagebox
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `module1.module2` without an explicit import if `module1` itself imports `module2`.  For instance, `os` internally imports one of several other path-handling modules (depending on the OS) and calls it `path`.  This `path` is then just a variable inside the `os` module that lets you access the `os.path` module.